# Scala parameter value does not compare correctly - checking for empty string value with if statement in view

Tags: scala

I have a view using Scala:

```
@(user: User = null, scripts: Html = Html(""), isLoggedIn: String = "", currentEmail: String=controllers.helpers.AccessMiddleware.getSessionEmail())(content: Html)
```

The currentEmail string is what I am interested in. It is empty or "" when a user is not logged into the system and contains an email value when logged in.

I can see that the value is empty or "" when opening the URL/application, but the if statement inside the view continually goes to the else part of the statement, display an empty string and not "Login":

```
<nav class="navmenu center">
    <ul>
        <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/signup">Register</a></li>
        <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>
        @if(currentEmail == "") {
            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/auth">Login</a></li>
        } else {                                        
            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/useraccount?email=@currentEmail">@currentEmail</a></li>
            <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It always determines that there is a value even though it is empty.  Here is the page source:

```
<nav class="navmenu center">
<ul>
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/signup">Register</a></li>
    <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/admin">Admin</a></li>

        <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/useraccount?email="></a></li>
        <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

</ul>
```

Is there another way to compare to an empty string?  Also, how do you make the currentEmail value lower case?  .toLowerCase() does not work...

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I forget to handle the case where currentEmail is null in the previous answer.  Posted the new answer Just check. I am pretty confident that this answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Option

`Option` with `forall` will handle the case where `currentEmail` is `null`

```
Option(currentEmail).forall(_.isEmpty)
```

Your code becomes

```
@if(Option(currentEmail).forall(_.isEmpty)) {
  <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/auth">Login</a></li>
} else {                                        
  <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/useraccount?email=@currentEmail">@currentEmail</a></li>
  <li class="scroll_btn"><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
}
```

Comment: @Dan Some one is downvoting the answer without stating the reason.

Comment: Interesting -- I upvoted it back to zero -- not sure what happened -- not sure who down voted...